# Serving two different angular apps at one domain with wildcard in path

Tags: angularjs, nginx, angular2-routing, nginx-location

Say I have a Dog app written in AngularJS and I'm now adding a new Grooming sub-app written in Angular4

Right now I have nginx serving `/api` to a backend php server with the `/api` prefix rewritten off (so it doesn't know it's in a sub-path) and `/` served by the frontend AngularJS app. These are two distinct apps, each in their own server directory. This works fine right now.

Now we are adding a Grooming app that is written in ng4 and it should be served out as though it were a module of the main app, but from an entirely different server dir, e.g. `/dogs/315/grooming`

If I hard-code the location to match `location /dogs/315/grooming` it loads the ng4 index.html and attempts to serve the app, but if I use regex `location ~ ^/dogs/([0-9]+)/grooming` it skips over it and loads the `/` location.

The Grooming app expects a url like `/dogs/315/*` to set the context, then it uses additional url segments for its own functionality.

The `try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.html` in the `location ~ ^/dogs/([0-9]+)/grooming` block keeps sending the child app back to the parent.

Here's some sample snippets, the grooming portion has been rewritten and changed many ways, I'm only including it as an example:

```
# This works
location ^~ /api {
    alias /home/forge/api.greatapp.com/current/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @api;
}

# This works
location @api {
    rewrite /api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?$query_string last;
}

# This doesn't work
location ~ ^/dog/([0-9]+)/grooming {
    alias /home/forge/dog-grooming.greatapp.com/current/dist/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @grooming;
}

# Nor this
location @grooming {
    rewrite ^/dog/([0-9]+)/grooming/(.*)$ /index.html break;
}

# This works
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.html;
}
```

Completely stuck on the grooming portions; tried so many things I could be going down the entirely wrong road.

Comment: If you replace `@grooming` by `=444`, do you get that code?

Comment: yes (15 characters)

Answer (score 0):

**Posting answer as comments as I need formatting**
Please try below

```
location ~ ^/dog/([0-9]+)/grooming/ {
    alias /home/forge/dog-grooming.greatapp.com/current/dist/;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Comment: That gives me a 404 but still serves the parent app (the `/` location serves)

Comment: Nothing useful in the logs (no error and access just shows the initial url `/dogs/913/grooming`. I did add headers to the `/` and grooming location blocks and neither is present after this change

Comment: Possible to get a git repo with some sample I can try on?